# How may I import a Node module in the client code of my Electron app?

Tags: electron, es6-modules

I'm building a board game from ES6 modules using Electron 2 (for [Chromium 61+](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232)) and the [esm shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) on the server side of things. This is the first time I've written isomorphic JavaScript, let alone ES6 modules; I intend to be able to run game logic on the client in single-player mode, and on the server in networked play mode. So far so good, I'm happy to report! And it's satisfying to not rely on any heavy transpilers.

Now, though, I have a problem: I intend to use types from [Immutable JS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js) on the client as well as the server, and I only know how to import them into the server code. Until now, all the import statements in the isomorphic code referred to other JS modules in the app, not to dependencies from npm. A module like the one below causes an "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'immutable'" runtime error in the client when the app loads:

```js
import Immutable from "immutable";
Immutable.List.of([]);
export { foo: {} };
```

In fact, I'm virtually certain that the import statement is failing because Chromium can't resolve "immutable" to a JS file. But how am I supposed to go about resolving it? And is there a way to resolve it that would work for any node module that is written to be isomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR - You can't without help of bundler like webpack as long as you're using npm modules.

Most of node.js package ecosystem is not ready for native module yet. About 99% of published package in npm currently using node.js's CommonJS module system, while there are very few module written to support esm (ES module syntax as well).

esm shim is intended to help latter - if module's written in esm and to be imported in current node.js version doesn't support it helps to resolve those modules. Opposite case doesn't work. Chromium can import your code directly which is written in native syntax, then try to resolve dependency module you specified and failed to resolve as 1. it doesn't know where to resolve (as it doesn't follow node.js's module resolution rules) 2. when it's available to resolve, actual import will fail cause module'll be cjs export instead of native.

Get back to TL;DR above - if the intention is achieving isomorphic code to run on both processes, use bundler accordingly.

Comment: Rats! Oh well, guess I'll find a lightweight bundler.